# Using fetch in a custom React hook - data is fetching twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My useFetch custom hook:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useFetch = (url, method = 'get') => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    (async () => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const res = await fetch(url, {
          signal: controller.signal,
          method: method.toUpperCase()
        });
        const json = await res.json();
        setResponse(json);
        setLoading(false);
        console.log('data fetched!!!', url);
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.name === 'AbortError') {
          setError('Aborted!');
        } else {
          setError(error);
        }
        setLoading(false);
      }
    })();

    return () => {
      controller.abort();
    };
  }, [url]);

  return { response, loading, error };
};

export default useFetch;
```

Using this hook inside the following component hierarchy: Catalog > Pagination.

Contents of Catalog component, where do i use a `useFetch` hook:

```
const Catalog = () => {
  const [limit] = useState(12);
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);

  const { response, loading, error } = useFetch(
    `http://localhost:3000/products?${new URLSearchParams({
      limit,
      offset
    })}`
  );

  // onPageChange fired from Pagination component, whenever i click on any of the page numbers.
  const onPageChange = index => {
    setOffset(index);
  };

  return (
    <Pagination
      items={response.data}
      count={response.count}
      pageSize={limit}
      onPageChange={onPageChange} 
    />
  );
}
```

Then, a Pagination component:

```
const Pagination = ({ items, count, pageSize, onPageChange }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
    if (items && items.length) {
      setPage(1)();
    }
  }, []);

  const setPage = page => e => {
    if (e) e.preventDefault();
    let innerPager = pager;

    if (page < 1 || page > pager.totalPages) {
      return null;
    }

    innerPager = getPager(count, page, pageSize);
    setPager(innerPager);
    onPageChange(innerPager.startIndex); // fires a function from the Catalog component
  };

const getPager = (totalItems, currentPage, pageSize) => {
    currentPage = currentPage || 1;
    pageSize = pageSize || 10;
    const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);

    let startPage, endPage;
    if (totalPages <= 10) {
      startPage = 1;
      endPage = totalPages;
    } else {
      if (currentPage <= 6) {
        startPage = 1;
        endPage = totalPages;
      } else if (currentPage + 4 >= totalPages) {
        startPage = totalPages - 9;
        endPage = totalPages;
      } else {
        startPage = currentPage - 5;
        endPage = currentPage + 4;
      }
    }

    let startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
    let endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + pageSize - 1, totalItems - 1);

    const pages = [...Array(endPage + 1 - startPage).keys()].map(
      i => startPage + i
    );

    return {
      totalItems,
      currentPage,
      pageSize,
      totalPages,
      startPage,
      endPage,
      startIndex,
      endIndex,
      pages
    };
  };

  return (
    <a className="page-link" href="#" onClick={e => setPage(page)(e)}>{page}</a>
  ); // shortened markup, i'm mapping paginator buttons from a getPager() function, each button has onClick event listener, which fires a setPage()()
}
```

A problem i currently experience now, is when i click on a pagination button, e.g: 1, 2, 3, my `useFetch` hook fires a first time with a correct offset value, for example: if i click on a 2nd page, offset would be equal to 12, if i click on a 3rd page, offset would be 24 and so on.

But in my case a `useFetch` hook is fired twice, first time with correct offset data, then a 2nd time, with initial offset data = 0. I'm only watching for the url changes inside `useFetch` hook, so my offset is changed just once, when i press on a pagination button.

Comment: You're saying that when you `useFetch` is called multiple times when you switch pages?

Comment: @goto1, when i switch pages by clicking on paginator items, i hope you get what i mean. It's something with `useFetch`'s local state i guess. Cause if i directly use `fetch` (not hook) inside a Catalog component, inside `useEffect` then i don't experience such issue.

Comment: I have a simplified working example that doesn't call `fetchData` twice when "switching" pages. I don't have the same exact APIs exposed so hard to replicate the exact setup. Perhaps I can share that and you can go off based on that.

Comment: Show me yours, it's 100% `useFetch` gives a headache. When i click on a paginator item, it does set correct `offset`, but after a few milliseconds, it switches to 0...

Comment: Have a look here - if this is something you can use I will submit as the answer - https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-shadow-svurd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Did you have any luck with my example?

Comment: Nope, rewriting my app as standalone one, because this one was used with laravel mix crap, i suspect it for this issue.

Comment: If your only issue is the `fetch` being called multiple times when you expect it be called once, then my example does just that, unless you're not showing the rest of the code that might be causing issues like the `setPager` functions and whatever code is responsible for setting the `pager` variable which is unclear what's any of this is doing.

Comment: @goto1, i just updated my question with `getPager` function. Please, take a look.

Comment: Just so I understand correctly, you say that when you call `onPageChange` inside `Pagination` it calls it once with the correct value, then calls it again with `0`? Do you call `onPageChange` anywhere else inside of that component or anywhere else?

Comment: I call `onPageChange` inside a `setPage` function, and `setPage` function is called in 2 cases: 1) when user clicks on a paginator itself; 2) in Paginator's component `useEffect` (it's called just once)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207463/discussion-between-alexander-kim-and-goto1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the conversation I had with OP, the main issue was the `useEffect` inside of `Pagination` component that would get triggered every time the component mounted. Even though the `useEffect` used an empty dependency array, which would prevent calling the `useEffect` hook once again when new `props` got passed, the `Pagination` component was getting unmounted because of the logic inside `Catalog`.

```js
// it more or less looked like this

const Catalog = () => {
  const {response, loading, error} = useFetch(...)

  const onPageChange = (index) => {...}

  if (loading) { return `Loading` }

  return <Pagination {...props} />
}
```

When `loading` was set back to true after calling `onPageChange` from the `Pagination` component, the `useEffect` hook inside of that same component would get called with a constant, `setPage(1)()` and reset the newly fetch items to the default `offset`, which is `1` in this case.

The `if (loading)` statement would unmount the `Pagination` component when it evaluated to `true`, causing the `useEffect` to run again inside `Pagination` because it was mounting for the "first time."

```js
const Pagination = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (...) setPage(1)()

    // empty array will prevent running this hook again
    // if props change and component re-renders, 
    // but DOES NOT get unmounted and mounted again
  }, [])
}
```

The OP needs to figure out the current page number inside of the `Pagination` component, hence the `useEffect` that called `setPage(1)()`. My suggestion was to move that business logic to the `useFetch` hook instead and figure out the current page number based on the response from the API.

I tried to come up with a solution and created a new hook that was more explicit, called `useFetchPosts`, that utilizes the `useFetch` hook, but returns the `page`, and `pageCount` along with other relevant data from the API.

```js
function useFetchPosts({ limit = 12, offset = 0 }) {
  const response = useFetch(
    `https://example.com/posts?${new URLSearchParams({ limit, offset })}`
  );
  const [payload, setPayload] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!response.data) return;

    const { data, count } = response.data;

    const lastItem = [...data].pop();
    const page = Math.floor(lastItem.id / limit);
    const pageCount = Math.ceil(count / limit);

    setPayload({
      data,
      count,
      page,
      pageCount
    });
  }, [response, limit, offset]);

  return {
    response: payload,
    loading: response.isFetching,
    error: response.error
  };
}
```

So now, instead of calculating what the current page is inside of `Pagination`, we can get rid of the `useEffect` hook that was causing issues and just simply pass that information to the `Pagination` component from `Catalog`.

```js
function Catalog() {
  const [limit] = React.useState(12);
  const [offset, setOffset] = React.useState(1);

  const { response, loading, error } = useFetchPosts({
    limit,
    offset
  });

  // ...

  return (
    <Pagination
      items={response.data}
      count={response.count}
      pageSize={limit}
      pageCount={response.pageCount}
      page={response.page}
      onPageChange={onPageChange}
    />
  );
}
```

This can be further optimized and perhaps done a little better, but here's an example that does what it's supposed to when different pages are clicked:

- [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-shadow-svurd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Hope this helps.